# Create json array and add objects to it on button click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I have form with datetime field and status(on/off) field, I have combined them in one json object `{"time":"2002-03-01T03:01:00.000Z","status":"off"}` 
onclick add button I need to add this opject to json array
the result should be like this:

```
[{"time":"2002-03-01T03:01:00.000Z","status":"off"},
{"time":"2002-03-01T03:01:00.000Z","status":"on"},
{"time":"2002-03-01T03:01:00.000Z","status":"off"},
{"time":"2002-03-01T03:01:00.000Z","status":"on"}]
```

adding object to array in each button click

Comment: what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You are not very clear about what you want it to look like, but you just need `array.push(object)` somewhere in your controller, which can be called from `ng-click` on some button.

Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [{
      "time": "2002-03-01T03:01:00.000Z",
      "status": "off"
    },
    {
      "time": "2002-03-01T03:01:00.000Z",
      "status": "on"
    },
    {
      "time": "2002-03-01T03:01:00.000Z",
      "status": "off"
    },
    {
      "time": "2002-03-01T03:01:00.000Z",
      "status": "on"
    }
  ];

  $scope.add = function(object) {
    $scope.array.push(object);
    $scope.st = null; // reset
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    Time: <input ng-model="tm" type="datetime-local" /><br>
    Status: <select ng-model="st" ng-options="x for x in ['on','off']"></select><br>
    <button ng-click="add({'time':tm,'status':st || 'off'})">Add</button>
    
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="obj in array">
      Time: {{obj.time | date}}, status: {{obj.status}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <pre>{{array | json}}</pre>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$scope.jsonStyleObject"> 

<button ng-model="$scope.jsonStyleObject"ng-click="addItemFunction($scope.jsonStyleObject)">Add to array of 
objects</button>
```

using `ng-click` in the view you can call a function in your controller(my preferred method is using 'vm.', however '$scope' should work too).